# Set object's yaw to be the same as camera

Tags: three.js

I'm playing around with Three.js, and I'm trying to figure out how to keep a box I have always facing away from the camera.

As of right now, the camera rotates around the box as you drag around. However, the box itself does not rotate. I want to make it so that as you rotate the camera, the box's yaw changes to face away from the camera.

How would I accomplish something like this? At first, I tried to set the .rotation.y of the box to the .rotation.y of the camera, however that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing should work. I have made a fiddle you can check out and compare your code to: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthewcooley/j4hUm/)

Here is a snippet from the animate function:

```
//quick and dirty way to spin the camera around the world center
camera.position.set(0, 0, 0); //move to world center
camera.rotation.y += 0.01; //rotate camera around world center
camera.translateZ(300); //move backwards

//match 
cube1.rotation.y = camera.rotation.y;
```

If you post your code here or on JSFiddle I might be able to help figure out what in your code is misbehaving